# The codomain of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $(S, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space. Consider a random variable $X: \Omega \rightarrow S$. We say that $X$ is discrete if its range $X(\Omega)$ is finite or countably infinite.

But what if we say that $X$ follows some known discrete distribution without specifying the codomain $S$? For example, suppose that $X$ is Poisson-distributed. Then the range of $X$ is the set of nonnegative integers. But what is its codomain $S$? Is it the set of nonnegative integers, the set of integers, or the set of real numbers? And what is the sigma algebra $\Sigma$? The same question could be asked e.g. if $X$ follows a binomial distribution.

Comment: Codomain is not unique.

Comment: If $X$ has discrete distribution then you can choose any set that contains the set $\{x|P(X=x)>0\}$ as codomain.  Just make things comfortable for yourself.

Comment: But what is the sigma algebra $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ is equipped with?

Comment: @mathslover These things don't mattter. Suppose $f: \Omega \to \Omega'$ is measurable. If you go to a smaller codomain $\Omega''\subseteq \Omega'$ that still contains the image, and you give $\Omega''$ the induced measurable structure, then $f$ is measurable if and only if $f': \Omega \to \Omega''$ is measurable. You can make the same exercise for continuity btw.